# C# Запустить библиотеку как отдельную программу

Tags: c#

Доброе утро, возможно ли библиотеку .Net 4.7.2, запустить как отдельное приложение?)
Имеется библиотека написанная мной, для программы iiko. Все было отлично пока у iiko не появилась возможность работать не как обычное приложение но и как служба(где отключены все окна, которые выводит библиотека). Хотелось бы запустить библиотеку как отдельное приложение для первоначальной настройки, а дальше можно и внутри iiko работать.
От сюда вопросы, как это сделать и как ограничить работу кода при запуске как отдельно приложение, что бы классы работающие именно с iiko, прошли мимо?

Comment: Написать приложение, подключить к нему библиотеку и использовать ее функции.

Comment: @aepot Укажите пожалуйста где об этом почитать, даже не знаю с чего начать и что искать) –

Comment: Что искать, как библиотеки в приложении использовать? Серьезно? :)

Comment: @aepot Я впервые с таким сталкиваюсь не ругайте))
Но я разобралась, все очень просто) просто добавить ссылку на dll в новом проекте =)